# Updated to wordpress 5.5.1 doesn't work

Tags: wp-admin, updates, mac

It's my first year in code and i am trying to make my own theme on wordpress.

Today i tried to updated wordpress in my local machine (xampp) on Mac
and this warning code appared :

`Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mimi/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173`

I tried to change all my folder to "read and write" like 777. But doesn't work..

Plugins : ACF and woocommerce..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user currently set on the file permissions matches what is in apache2/httpd.conf. The part of httpd.conf that specifies the user is as follows and you'll need to restart Apache after any changes.

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.                                                                                                                     Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Its my httpd.conf everythings is ok ?